# Как использовать 2 библиотеки разных версий (Java Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Нужна помощь я хочу использовать 2 библиотеки разных версий 
    `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'` и
     `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` Поскольку 1.0.0 хорошо работает до 6 android  а  1.1.0 работает после 6+ 
как это можно реализовать
спасибо.

Comment: а можете привести пример с чем 1.0.0 лучше работает в андройд до 6 версии?

Comment: Смотрите библиотекой 1.0.0 до 6 все более менее корректно  после 6 во время обновления страницы то включается белая  тема то черная как захочет.  библиотекой 1.1.0  все хорошо работает после 6 отображается при обновлении страницы все корректно но до 6 когда вот включил режим  черной темы вышел из программы убрал её из диспетчера потом повторно зашёл  и у тебя тупо черный экран и всё.

Comment: Приходиться на два стула сесть что бы и там и там работало и было хорошо

Comment: На два стула сесть не выйдет, но с помощью [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors) можно сделать два варианта сборки с разными библиотеками и, соответственно собирать либо два APK, либо Bundle. У маркета есть механизм публикации нескольких версий сборок - каждая будет доступна подходящему устройству. Bundle вообще придуман именно для этого.

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы подключаете библиотеку, то она распаковывается у вас и делает зависимости. По факту, вы не сможете две сразу установить и отследить запускаемый андроид, чтобы выбрать какую использовать.
Рекомендую выбрать одну и на основе ее пофиксить проблему.